# onclick turtle method in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am re-creating the game of x and os, but I can't seem to get the onclick method in python3 to work here's my code:

```
def hide(t):
    t.hideturtle()

def begin():
    global playersTurn
    if playersTurn == 0:
        playerOnesTurn.showturtle()
        playerOnesTurn.onclick(hide)
    else:
        playerTwosTurn.showturtle()
        playerTwosTurn.onclick(hide)
```

I'm displaying an image in the turtle `playerOnesTurn`and `playerTwosTurn`.
When I run the program and I want the turtle to hide when the player clicks on the image, it gives me the following error and I have not found a solution:

```
TypeError: hide() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: tried putng a second argument in hide and then printing them both and see what is passed in?

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick()` handler expects a function that takes the x & y positions as arguments.  So, instead do something like:

```
playerOnesTurn.onclick(lambda x, y: playerOnesTurn.hideturtle())
```

Other comments: if you're only checking `playersTurn`, not changing it, then you don't need the `global playersTurn` statement; when you enable `onclick()` for one player, you might want to disable it for the other player by doing `playerTwosTurn.onclick(None)`.

Comment: Thank you cdlane. I have changed my code and I no longer get the error but the thing is that it is now closing the window completely, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AbigailLeahSingh, you're not calling `turtle.exitonclick()` are you?  If so, replace it with `turtle.mainloop()` otherwise you've two onclick handlers.